# Executable not found in directory after using command g++ -o exename.exe filename.cpp

Tags: c++, mingw

I am trying to run a simple c++ program on my new computer with an Windows 10 OS. I have downloaded the G++ compiler with the MinGW installer, I have also added C:\MinGW\bin to my paths environment variable. My code compiles but when I try to make an executable it isn't being made and placed in to the directory. Ill place the commands I use and output below:

```
PS C:\Users\John Alvarez\Documents\School\Practice> ls


Directory: C:\Users\John Alvarez\Documents\School\Practice


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        11/6/2017   2:16 PM            101 helloWorld.cpp


PS C:\Users\John Alvarez\Documents\School\Practice> g++ -o cpp.exe 
.\helloWorld.cpp
PS C:\Users\John Alvarez\Documents\School\Practice> ls


Directory: C:\Users\John Alvarez\Documents\School\Practice


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        11/6/2017   2:16 PM            101 helloWorld.cpp


PS C:\Users\John Alvarez\Documents\School\Practice> cpp.exe
```

When I try to run cpp.exe nothing happens. Why would this be happening?

I'm doing all of this on Windows Powershell.

Comment: Can you show the output of a `ls` of the directory holding only `helloWorld.cpp`, then the compiler call and its *complete* output, and the result of another `ls`?

Comment: Are you running the command to build from a Windows console window (the old "DOS prompt"), or a Bash (or other shell) console window?

Comment: Could it be you don't have the necessary permissions to create files in that directory? @Someprogrammerdude: That seems to be a PowerShell...?!? (The "PS" at the beginning of the prompt.)

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing happens' when you try to run cpp.exe? Do you get an error?

Comment: By the way, and what I just realized, is that the reason for why you can still run `cpp.exe` without errors and nothing happening, is because that's the name of the standalone C preprocessor program. I suggest you name it differently.

Comment: I have tried naming it other things, and the same result happens.By nothing happens I mean it seems to just compile with no errors but doesn't make the executable.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @DevSolar I ran power shell in administrator and it worked.

Comment: Which is of course not a good solution (running as admin). Set the directory permissions correctly.